# VHDL difference between => and <=

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I keep forgetting and its difficult to search for the answer in a textbook or the Internet.

Comment: I am not referring to greater/less than or equal to btw.

Comment: Okay thanks guys I marked the accepted answer. In my context its for vector assignment but can be used for other things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VHDL: signals and ports on which side of the "arrow" =>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206776/vhdl-signals-and-ports-on-which-side-of-the-arrow)

Comment: => and <= are lexical elements called compound delimiters used in both expressions as relational operators and in syntactic productions (signal assignment statement for <=, and case statement alternatives or association elements in association lists for subprogram calls, port maps, generic maps or array and record aggregates for =>). Their usage is syntactically distinct. Contrary to the book Digital Mclogic Design by Bryan Mealy VHDL has no assignment operators. Assignment is a basic operation found in assignment statements and object and interface declarations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, `<=` is assignment.

```
signal <= A or B;
```

`=>` is syntax used for case statements like so:
(Stolen from http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/sequential.html)

```
case  my_val  is
  when 1 =>  -- This is kind of like how the : operator is used for switch in many languages
    a:=b;
  when 3 =>
    c:=d;
    do_it;
  when others =>
    null; -- do nothing
end case;

end case;
```

`=>` can also be used in array assignments

```
myVector <= (1=>'1', OTHERS=>'0');  -- assigns ('0','1','0','0') to "myVector"
```

Source: http://www.eda.org/comp.lang.vhdl/html3/gloss_example.html

Comment: Hmm that is close to the scenario but I encountered it while working with registers. SHould have stated that first D: 

ie: others=> (others=>'0')

Comment: Are you referring to vector assignments?  I updated my answer.  When working with vectors, you can use this operator to assign values to specific parts of the vector.

Answer (score 8):

A means to memorize when to use `=>` and when to use `<=` is to think as follow.

**`<=` as an assignment for signal as target (for variable it is `:=`).**

Examples:

```
y <= a + b + c; --y is a signal
v := a + b +c; --v is a variable
```

**`=>` as mapping**.

Example for component explicit mapping (recommended style IMHO):

```
my_instance : my_component
port map(
  port1 => my_signal1
);
```

Example for function explicit mapping (useful when parameters are not trivial):

```
my_signal <= my_function(parameter1 => something1, parameter2 => something2);
```

Example for array explicit mapping

```
type array_type is array(0 to 1) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
constant my_array : array_type := (0 => x"AB", 1 => x"CD");
```

Example for record explicit mapping

```
type record_type is record
a : natural;
b : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
end record;
constant my_record: record_type := (a => 0, b => "101");
```

The advantage is this style allows you to do the mapping in the order of your choice (not necessarily the order in the definition of the component/function...). Moreover in the particular case of array with only one item, it is required.

Finally, with the `=>`, the keyword `others` allows to map all the remaining stuff that hasn't already mapped.

Example to assign array:

```
type array_type is array(0 to 5) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
constant my_array : array_type := (0 => x"AB", 1 => x"CD", others => (others => '0'));
```

Comment: The last example constant declaration is of an array type whose value is assigned the value of an array aggregate whose *association* elements provide the value through an *association list*.

Answer (score 0):

`<=` represents the assignment operator while `=>` is used in the case statement, for example:

```
case sel is
  when "01"   => line <= "1";
  when others => line <= "0";
end case
```

sets `line` to "1" in case `sel` is "01" and to "0" otherwise.

`=>` is also used in structural code in port maps.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `<=` is known as a
signal assignment operator to highlight its true purpose. The signal assignment operator specifies a relationship between signals. In other words, the signal on the left side of the signal assignment operator is dependent upon the signals on the right side of the operator.

(Source: Digital_Mclogic_Design by Bryan Mealy,  Section: The Signal Assignment Operator: “<=”, page 339)

I couldn't find anything specific on the `=>` operator.

Comment: Signal assignment is a basic operation and there is no signal assignment operator, it's in  a signal assignment statement. The <= is just part of the syntax. See IEEE Std 1076.