# Signals and ports on which side of the "arrow" =>

Tags: vhdl

How do I know where the port/signal/value should be placed on which side of the arrows?

I noticed that by switching
`port_a => x` to `x <= port_a` which seems very equal, I got an error.
Also, `x => port_a` doesn't work.

I even do not know which way the arrows should point.

Comment: I'm voting to mark this as duplicate of [VHDL difference between => and <=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988098/vhdl-difference-between-and)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<=` is an assignment - specifically a signal assignment, driving a signal with a value from somewhere else.  For a physical analogy, the thing on the right hand side drives a value onto the left hand side.

`=>` is a port mapping from a pin to a signal.  This is not an assignment - the physical analogy might be soldering a pin to a wire.

You can only do "soldering" to instantiations, so `=>` mapping only happens inside a `port map`. And there, "pins" *always* go on the left (because that's what the language rules say), which is why you can't do `x <= port_a` in a `port map`.

Answer (score 2):

Signal assignments go from right to left using `<=`.
The right side must be an input signal from the entity or a signal declared in a process.
The left side can be an output signal (or input/buffer) from the entity, a signal declared in the process or a variable declared in the process.

Beside port mapping mentioned in other answers, the `=>` arrow is also used for a totally different thing - to construct vectors.
For example, if v is a 4 bit vector, then `v <= (others => '0')` will assign `"0000"` to `v`. The `=>` within the parentheses is a shortcut for assigning different values in different places inside the vector.

Answer (score 0):

If `=>` is for a ports list then how is this possible? Please note that `clk_40Mhz_i` is a pin.

```
COMPONENT clk_wiz_v3_5 is 

PORT  
 (-- Clock in ports
  CLK_IN1           : in     std_logic;
  -- Clock out ports
  CLK_OUT1          : out    std_logic;
  -- Status and control signals
  RESET             : in     std_logic;
  LOCKED            : out    std_logic
);

END COMPONENT;

xclk_wiz_v3_5: clk_wiz_v3_5
   PORT MAP (
     CLK_IN1          => clk_40Mhz_i,
     -- Clock out ports
     CLK_OUT1         => clk_40Mhz,
     -- Status and control signals
     RESET            => pic_fpga_reset,
     LOCKED           => clk_locked   
   );

   pic_fpga_reset          <= not(processor_fpga_resetn_i);
   reset                   <= not(clk_locked);
```